# Result is not showing when I run my app second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this quiz app and it shows the result when I run it firts time, but when I click Play again and run the app again, it is not showing the result. I know I have issue in following code, but not able to figure out it. Please help -

```
//This function is for reseting the quiz
    var resetQuiz = function() {
            if (resetCounter++ > 1 || quizOver || confirm('Are you sure you want to reset the quiz?')) {
                counter = 0;
                quizOver = false;
                results = {count: 0, answers: [], currentScore: 0};
                scoreNode.addClass('no_score').text('');
                questionBlock.show();
                nextQuestion();
            }
    };
    //This function handle the results
    var showResults = function() {
            answersBlock.empty();
            questionBlock.hide();
            showResult.text('You answered ' + results.currentScore + '% of '
                + 'the questions correctly.');
            quizOver = true;
            actionButton.text('Play again');
    };
```

Full app is here - http://jsfiddle.net/varunksaini/J5qVd/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `var buttonAction = function() {` you are doing `showResult.hide();` after you click 'Play Again' which sets it to have `display:none`

However, you are never calling `showResult.show();` in your showResults() function.  So it remains with `display:none`.  You just need to call `showResults.show();` afer you change the text.

```
var showResults = function() {
        answersBlock.empty();
        questionBlock.hide();
        showResult.text('You answered ' + results.currentScore + '% of '
            + 'the questions correctly.');
        quizOver = true;
        showResult.show(); //Show the results if they have been hidden
        actionButton.text('Play again');
};
```